# My emulator shows google map location but on device I am only seeig google map it is not fetching location

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

My google map code works fine in emulator showing location.
But on running on device I see google map but it is not showing me the exact location

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for the map is not coming can be :

1. Network issue (Check internet access in device).
2. Check whether the API key and the keystore are matching.

Check the logcat and see what error is showing over there when you try to launch the map.

Comment: yes but I am seeing goole map it is not showing blank screen it just does not bring up the location.

Comment: can you please check the android OS verion on emulator and Device. If it is a marshmallow device, then check whether you have appropriate permission for using location.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I am new to android please can you tell me how can I check permission?

Comment: If your device is marshmallow, go to the app info and there you can see an item for permission. Click on that and you can see various permissions used by the app and their status.